# React stateless component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BackButton } from 'components/button'

class LandingHeader extends Component {

    render() {

        const back = (props) => <BackButton forcedBackUrl={props.back.forcedBackUrl} />

        return (
             <div>
                 {back}
                 {this.props.children}
             </div>
         )
    }

}

export default LandingHeader
```

If i put the `<BackButton>` component directly it works but if I use a stateless component and return it inside this one it wont. What im missing?

Im following the official documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) and I can't see whats wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `<BackButton />`?

Comment: I changed the stateless function to `const back = () => <div>Button</div>` and happens the same. I don't think back button has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @JonathanCalb Look at my solution below... you need to execute the function passing through the prop if you want to keep the structure you have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared a `ReactClass` but you aren't *rendering* it - you have to turn it into a `ReactElement`:

```
const Back = (props) => <BackButton forcedBackUrl={props.forcedBackUrl} />

return (
  <div>
    <Back {...this.props.back} />
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the facebook documentation that you provided they give the example of :

```
const HelloMessage = (props) => <div>Hello {props.name}</div>;
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Sebastian" />, mountNode);
```

and not just returning {HelloMessage}

therefore replace

`{back}`

with

```
<Back />
```

and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the props into the component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BackButton } from 'components/button'

    class LandingHeader extends Component {

        render() {

            const back = (props) => <BackButton forcedBackUrl={props.back.forcedBackUrl} />

            return (
                 <div>
                     {back(this.props)}
                     {this.props.children}
                 </div>
             )
        }

    }
```